# capistrano deploys wrong directory

Tags: ruby, git, capistrano

I am newbie in capistrano , i am able to deploy my ruby application from git to the server successfully , but instead of deploying the code directly it creates 2 directories namely **current** and **releases** . How to come out from it ?

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. It's how capistrano works.

Each time you deploy a new release is created in the releases folder. Once the deploy is complete the current symlink is updated to point at the newly created release.

This way

- you don't need to update webserver configurations on each release
- inprogress deploys aren't used until they are ready
- it's possible to switch back to an old release